# ordering of variable in joint distribution

Tags: bayesian, joint-distribution

I was reading a lecture regarding representing a join distribution as a graphical model. The lecture is available here (on page 4 of the slides):

http://www.maths.lth.se/matematiklth/personal/sminchis/mlc/lecture-6.pdf

In the lecture, it says:

l.h.s. (left hand side) is symmetric with respect to a,b,c. But right hand side is not symmetric with respect to a,b,c  , could someone give me some hints or reasoning as to why the author says so?

My reasoning that they are the same is because:

P(a,b,c) = P(c|a,b) * P(a|b)*P(b) = P(a|b,c)*P(b|c)*P(c) = P(b|a,c)*P(a|c)*P(c)

We can factor the joint distribution in any order or way no??? and still have the same joint distribution right?

My question is I don't understand why the author says the R.H.S is not symmetric with respect to a,b,c. They must be some concepts here I am not getting.

Would be great if someone can explain little more to me.

Thank you.

Comment: On the slide it confirms what you are saying: From the joint distribution any factorization is possible. All it is saying imo is that once you arrive at a factorization you have a directed graph representation where you cannont simply switch nodes, eg. You have parents and childs.

Comment: But could you explain exactly what it means by "R.H.S is not symmetric with respect to a,b,c.".   What does that sentence exactly mean?   Could you give me an example please. It would be very helpful if you could explain little more by using example. Thank you. Because I still not quite get what the author is saying there.